# how to make button fit line height

Tags: html, button

I've put a button in a line of text but altho the button itself is about the same height as the text in the line, it makes the height of the lines with buttons greater than those lines without buttons. I don't want this as I need to have two sets of lines with equal heights.
Here's the html:

```
<p class="thai2eng"><span class="color_up audio" id="t1ee01">Where can you go? </span>   <button type="button" class="bt1ee">Test</button></p>
```

Line height is 1.0em. I haven't tried the input tag as I understand (tho I may be mistaken) that the button tag supports images better. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<p style="vertical-align: super">
    <span class="color_up audio" id="t1ee01">Where can you go? </span>
    <button type="button" class="bt1ee">
        Test
    </button>
</p>
```

Comment: this only worked when the style was attached to the button, and then the button moved but the discrepancy between the line heights remained. In the end, simply increasing the line height to 1.8em worked OK.